# Entity Framework -- How to find the inverse property of a navigational property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I'm wondering how I can correctly determine the inverse navigational property of another property. I have successully been able to do so (see code below), but I have no idea if it's actually correct. It seems to work though, but I'm currently a little worried about deploying this code.

For instance, I have two object types:

```
class Paper {

  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Person Author { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
}

class Person {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Paper> Papers { get; set; }
}
```

Now, how can I determine at runtime if the Person-type has an inverse property of the 'Papers'-property (i.e. 'Author'), or none at all?

Here is an excerpt from my code. Is this the correct way to go about it? See comments.

```
var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)someDbContext).ObjectContext;

// First, compile a preliminary list of relationship end members to type with navigational property.
// This list can then be used to compile a dictionary in the format of type, propertyName = type, propertyName, to determine the inverse (if any).

var relationshipEndMembers = new Dictionary<RelationshipEndMember, Tuple<EntityType, NavigationProperty>>();

foreach (var s in context.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace).BaseEntitySets)
{
    foreach (var m in s.ElementType.Members)
    {
        var associationEndMember = m as AssociationEndMember;

        if (associationEndMember != null)
        {
            var type = associationEndMember.GetEntityType();

            // Is this the correct way of looping through all navigation properties? s.ElementType.Members.OfType<NavigationProperty>() only resulted in a very few of my navigational properties!

            foreach (var p in type.DeclaredNavigationProperties)
            {
                if (!relationshipEndMembers.ContainsKey(p.FromEndMember))
                    relationshipEndMembers.Add(p.FromEndMember, new Tuple<EntityType, NavigationProperty>(type, p));
            }
        }
    }
}

// Compile the result

var navigationProperties = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, Tuple<string, string>>();

foreach (var p in relationshipEndMembers)
{
    Tuple<EntityType, NavigationProperty> inverse;

    if (relationshipEndMembers.TryGetValue(p.Value.Item2.ToEndMember, out inverse))
        navigationProperties.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(p.Value.Item1.Name, p.Value.Item2.Name), new Tuple<string, string>(inverse.Item1.Name, inverse.Item2.Name));
}

// Now it is possible to query the navigationProperties with a type and property as the key, to obtain (if any) the inverse type and property
```

Is it necessary to check `ToEndMember.DeleteBehavior` if it is not `OperationAction.None` in the code above?

Thanks for any help! -Emil

Comment: Is your question _"Does `DeclaredNavigationProperties` contain all declared navigation properties?"_?

Comment: I guess so, yes. And should I do it this way at all? Is there a smarter way? And is it necessary to check ToEndMember.DeleteBehavior? And lastly, will it work for all properties in any conceivable future? I kind of hotchpotched this code together and to be honest I'm not sure what I'm doing :)